# Splice() does not make the array empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-splice

I have arrays x,y and z.
While iterating through x, based on a condition I need to keep removing the elements from z. Here's what I am trying to do:

```
var x = ["test0", "test1", "test2"];
var y = ["test0", "test1", "test2"];
var z = ["test0", "test1", "test2"];

function myFunction(){
    for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
        for (var j=0; j<y.length; j++){
            if(x[i] == y[j]){
                z.splice(i,1);
            }
        }

    }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
}
```

At the end of iteration, z should get empty. But it is always showing me 'test1' element remaining.
Since the correct index is not getting spliced I tried to do `z.splice(i--,1)` but that did not work either.

Please advise what is the best way to resolve this ?

Comment: Just update your splice method parameters like this: z.splice(0,1); it should work

Comment: @AliBaig That only works in this test case. The poster is trying to remove indices that match in the other arrays, and that is not always going to be index `0`. If they wanted to remove all elements, it would be easier to assign the variable to a new empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of keeping track of the moving indices, you can find the current index using `indexOf()`

```
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
    for (var j=0; j<y.length; j++){
        if(x[i] == y[j]){
            z.splice( z.indexOf(x[i]) , 1 );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This assumes that `z[i] === x[i]`, it would behave differently if `var z = ["test2", "spaghetti", "pamplemousse"];`

Answer (score 3):

It's quite easy to understand, if you create some sort of a table. The problem is that after the first splice, the index of z is not like the indexes of x and y:

```
x[0] = j[0] : i = 0 -> z.splice(0, 1); - test0 is removed - z = ["test1", "test2"];
x[1] = j[1] : i = 1 -> z.splice(1, 1); - test2 is removed - z = ["test1"];
x[2] = j[2] : i = 2 -> z.splice(2, 1); - nothing is removed - z = ["test1"];
```

Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
    var removed = 0; // removed items counter
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
            if (x[i] == y[j]) {
                z.splice(i - removed, 1); // subtract removed counter from index
                removed++; // increment removed counter
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As answers have said, your problem is that splicing *z* means the indexes and values are no longer aligned between the arrays. A common alternative to keeping track of removed indexes when removing elements from any kind of list is to iterate from the end to the start, e.g.

```js
var x = ["test0", "test1", "test2"];
var y = ["test0", "test1", "test2"];
var z = ["test0", "test1", "test2"];

function myFunction(){
    for (var i=x.length; i>0; ){
        for (var j=y.length; j> 0; ){
            if(x[--i] == y[--j]){
                z.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
    }
    document.write('"' + z.join() + '"');
}

myFunction();
```

And if you use some of the syntactic sugar introduced with ES5, *reduceRight* helps to reduce the amount of code:

```
function myFunction(){
  x.reduceRight(function(n, x, i) {
    y.reduceRight(function(n, y) {
      if (x == y) z.splice(i, 1)
    }, null);
  }, null)
  document.write('"' + z.join() + '"');
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution.

Comment: Thank you all of you for your suggestions/solutions. The solution given by charlietfl worked best for me as my array z is always the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could resolve it by keeping track of the number of removed elements from z:

```
var numRemoved = 0;
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
    for (var j=0; j<y.length; j++){
        if(x[i] == y[j]){
            z.splice( i - numRemoved++ , 1 );
        }
    }
}
```